# Firebase hosting emulator over https

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-tools

Is it possible to have `https://localhost:5000` for the hosting firebase emulator setup.

I need this since i am developing a word addin and it requires https.

I have tried using a devtunnel and ngrok but no luck there.

Is there a way to provide dev certificate or something

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: The general existing advice is to use ngrok. If it's not working, then you should show what you're doing that doesn't work the way you expect.  [The emulator is not going to support this itself any time soon.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1908)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the firebase emulator, but from your question it sounds like this is simple http traffic, so you just run a reverse proxy in front of it (nginx, apache http, caddy) that does the TLS termination and forwards the traffic to your firebase emulator over http.

Eg. with caddy this is very simple: https://caddyserver.com/docs/quick-starts/reverse-proxy#https-from-client-to-proxy

You'll then maybe still need to use a different certificate, depending on whether or not the client accepts self-signed ones.

Comment: If its so easy whaty didn't the google team already done that? Their support of local development is non-existent there is no Cloud tasks emulator you can not serve over https you can not easily integrate with thw most popular IDE its like bunch of high school students made it and not google. I think they should learn from Angular team